# Best way to move a huge amount of point?

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, glsl, vertex-shader

I'm using threejs to render around 2 000 000 points by using PointClouds. I would like to make each point move. To do that, I have the beginning position and the end position.

So, I'm looking for the best way to do it. And three ideas came up :

- Do a custom shader, where I modify the position of each vertex following this function : f(t) = beginning*(1-t)+end*t. With t varying from 0 to 1.
  But I can't send so big arrays to the shader (2 millions vec3 to know end position). **Is it possible for each vertex to send the specific end vec3 ?** So I would have : uniform vec3 end, instead of uniform vec3 end[2097152].
- precalculate the position and send the result to shader.
- precalculate the position by using web workers and then send the result to the shader.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could do my animation ?

I'm really new to the all the shader stuff and I don't fully understand web workers yet. So I might be wrong with what I say. Don't hesitate to make me aware of it :P

Thanks !

edit: dunno why, but stackoverflow doesn't want me to say Hi at the beginning of the message. Hi !

editV2 : Executing the moving code on the main thread.

```
    var moving = setInterval(function() 
    { 
        var time = t;
        var iTime = 1-time;

        for(var i = 0; i < 2097152;i++)
        {
            scene.children[1].geometry.attributes.position.array[i*3] = before[i].x*iTime+after[i].x*time;
            scene.children[1].geometry.attributes.position.array[i*3+1] = before[i].y*iTime+after[i].y*time;
            scene.children[1].geometry.attributes.position.array[i*3+2] = before[i].z*iTime+after[i].z*time;
        }
        scene.children[1].geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
        t+=1/60;
        if(t>1)
        {
            clearInterval(moving);
        }
    },5);
```

editV3 :

As WestLangley explained me, I need to use attributes so my code looks like that :
Vertex shader :

```
        uniform float size;
        uniform float t;
        attribute vec3 endPosition;

        void main() {

            vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position*(1.0-t)+endPosition*t, 1.0 );

            gl_PointSize = size / length( mvPosition.xyz );

            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

        }
```

And I add the attributes with the BufferGeometry :

```
geometry.addAttribute('position' , new THREE.BufferAttribute( positionArray, 3 ));
geometry.addAttribute('endPosition' , new THREE.BufferAttribute( endPositionArray, 3 ));
```

It's moving, but it's just getting smaller and smaller. It seems that endPosition*t is equal to 0 for the vertex shader.
Do I have a wrong function ? or did I miss something with the declaration of endPosition ?
I'm quite sure endPosition must not be a vec3, but something with buffer, but for the moment I didn't found it.

Thanks for your help :)

EditV4: 
Ok I found where my problem was, I needed to specify the shaderMaterial that I wanted to add :

```
var attributes = {
    endPosition: { type:'v3', value:null }
}
```

As position already existed and was functionning, I didn't pay attention to that fact.

Thanks everyone ! Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi! SO is a Pavlov experiment, human behavior not allowed [8-]--|-[

Comment: How about iteratively pass a smaller chuck of vertices to your function? Maybe slice 100 vertices and pass in each time?

Comment: Do you talk about the shader ?, if yes I don't know how to do it ^^". As far as I understood the vertex shader, the code that is in the vertex shader is executed for each vertex, so I don't know how  I could get it.

I tryied moving my points on the main thread, with the code in the editV2 of my post. But as expected, that is quite slow :/ . It goes down to 5 fps.

Comment: You should update the positions in the vertex shader. You need one uniform: `t`. Update `t` in the render loop. Your `BufferGeometry` needs two attributes: `position` and `endPosition`.

Comment: this post should be very helpful: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/

Comment: WestLangley, that's exactly what I want to do, 

But I don't now what type to declare endPosition. I show you what I got in the edit V3 of my post.

Comment: Here is an example implementation of the above solution on NPM, displaying over a million points: https://www.npmjs.com/package/animated-points